# ios13 settings bundle with child pane crashes Settings.app on real device

Tags: settings.bundle, ios13

Using an iPad mini4 (A1538), running iOS 13 beta 6, using XCode 11 beta 5...
Create a new iOS project using the Single View App template in XCode 11. Add a Settings.bundle with the root containing only two items:

1. Child Pane
2. Text Field

Create a child pane plist file, add it to the Settings.bundle and link it to the root Child Pane entry via its Filename property, per normal Apple Settings Bundle guidelines. For the child pane create two items:

1. Group Specifier (seems to be required else nothing shows up in child pane page at all)
2. Text Field

The names, default values etc of the text field entries themselves aren't important, pick anything. Build the app and run it. On the simulator the Settings.app will work as expected - you can navigate to the child pane and see and interact with the text field on it. Running it on a real device will result in the Settings.app crashing when you select the child pane control to navigate to it. If you remove all controls, in our case the single text field entry, from the child pane plist it will not crash. Adding any entries at all other than the Group Specifier seems to trigger the crash. This works fine on iOS versions prior to 13.

Debug vs release build doesn't matter. Appears to be a new iOS 13 bug. Can someone recreate and confirm? Steps are listed but a sample project can be provided if necessary - I purposefully used the default template with minimal changes to prove its not a WOMM type issue

Comment: FYI submitted bug to Apple as well

Comment: I have the same problem, still not solved in beta 7. I have also submitted a bug report. Beta 5 already had weird issues with Settings,bundle, as in not showing all settings, but this is even worse.

Comment: I too have seen other Settings issues that also cause crashes. It's like they overhauled Settings.app for the worse

Comment: Still crashing in beta 8.

Comment: Looking at the crash logs it seems they now use SwiftUI to display the content of a Settings.bundle. So they are re-implementing a lot of stuff, with the risk of 'forgetting' some lesser used features.

Comment: Anyone found any fixes for this yet?

Comment: Any progress on this issue yet? I posted [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58044107/8289095) before I realised this had already been asked.

Comment: This seems to have been resolved on my devices running 13.1 beta.

Comment: bug still present on 13.1 beta 4

Comment: bug still present in 13.1 released version :(

Comment: @Sashah I just installed the release version of 13.1 and it works fine. Are the plists formatted as settings plists?

Comment: @Chris thank you, I mistakenly thought that this was the same as my related issue. In my issue the child pane is two levels deep and it crashes on back button press. I finally found someone else with my exact crash: https://github.com/mono0926/LicensePlist/issues/105

Answer (score 5):

NB:a A separate bug leading to a settings crash in iOS 13 is related to using the value type "Number" in an item of type "PSTextFieldSpecifier".

Comment: We had a crash because we were writing a default value as NSInteger to PSTextFieldSpecifier, before converting to NSString. This was working until iOS 13.

Comment: getting the same issue from comment above

Comment: This was the cause of my crash. I stored an integer into the preferences that was represented using a text field in settings. Doing manual string <-> int conversion fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this crash issue by change table view style to Group style on Child Pane. You just need to add 1 item with type is PSGroupSpecifier.

[image: Child Pane Group Table Style]

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. According to crashlogs the exception was caused by SwiftUI.

However, iOS 13.3 update has fixed it.